# eqref: how to use most recent label instead of the very last label

Tags: labels, ref

When I use the same label multiple times in one document, only the last definition is used for the reference. Is it possible to change that behaviour such that each time a certain label is referenced, only the most recent one is used without modifying the code within the `document`? (I quite often have to copy documents from different authors into one single document, so replacing/modifying every single `label/eqref` would be cumbersome.)

Here my MCVE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Test
\[ 1 = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1} \]
First eq: \eqref{eq1} (references first one, but I want it to reference second one)
\[ 2 = 2 \tag{2}\label{eq1} \]
Second eq: \eqref{eq1} (actually references second one)
\end{document}
```

Comment: obviously any part of latex can be redefined but really I wouldn't do that having duplicate labels just should be an error. If you make it a non-error in tex, it will bite you if you ever need to incorporate the document into anything else or translate to html or do anything. Just for printing it's easier but if you are using hyperref then an internal anchor has already been made for eq1 at the first equation so only options at the second equation would really be to give an error or ignore.

Comment: I know my idea is not really a clean solution, but I thought perhaps someone knows a "quick and dirty" trick to achieve this. These documents aren't going to be edited much further anyway, so it should not be a big problem in my case. =)

Comment: Open a document sent to you by one of your coauthors and replace all occurrences of `ref{` with `ref{jane:` and all occurrences of `label{` with `label{jane:`.  The `xref' package is useful for a related, but not identical problem.

Comment: The entire `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism, including the `\label`-`\eqref` variant, is built on the premise that the labels are unique, i.e., that no two objects are ever assigned the same `\label`. How difficult is it to go through a merged document and edit some of the `\label` directives? Hint: If you have duplicate labels, you should be getting copious warnings. Just comb through the log file and let the warning messages be your guide to where the duplicates may be located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This semi-automates the comment from @jPi.  Using `\labelid` one can append unique identifiers to each `\label` and `\ref` (`\eqref` calls `\ref`, so no change needed).  If you want to access an equation for a different id, one can still use `\oldref` (but not `\eqref`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldlabel=\label
\let\oldref=\ref
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1.\labelid}}%
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1.\labelid}}%

\newcommand{\labelid}{init}% unique identifief for each paper

\usepackage{amsmath}% must go after redefinition

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelid}{alpha}
Test
\[ 1 = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1} \]
First eq: \eqref{eq1}

\renewcommand{\labelid}{beta}
\[ 2 = 2 \tag{2}\label{eq1} \]
Second eq: \eqref{eq1}

\end{document}
```